# Can I (relatively easily) test ZK interfaces in Watir?

Tags: watir, zk

How easily will Watir interact with a ZK interface? If "not at all" do you have any recommendations for automated testing of the web interface for me?

Edit: Another way to put this would be can I test a Spring/ZK generated page (Ajax/JScript). I found another issue too: I need not to use a proxy to test (like Sahi does) if at all possible.

Edit: I have been testing ZK interfaces now for quite some time. With a higher knowledge of Watir (and now webdriver) I can say it's definitely possible. Timing isn't usually an issue, but finding the elements certainly can be as the ids are dynamically generated. I recommend a strong, maintainable, object oriented approach with a powerful and dynamic DSL, or you'll be listing every element on the page in a custom built object library of some sort. So... it works, but it needs extra effort.

Comment: So far the answer is "Yes". I will be testing an older version of ZK interface and then a newer version in time, so I will try to keep this question updated with any problems I run into that are a direct result of a ZK generated interface. So far it's just dynamic IDs, but Watir is too good to be outdone by them. You may need to use the hardware left click in rare cases (search google for "watir hardware click" and you'll find the necessary code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about this: http://zssdemo.zkoss.org/ you can take a look at the DOM output, it's atrocious, but possible to test it with Watir. I've dealt with some apps that generate awful output like that. It makes for a challenge. :) Search the Watir google group for testing Ajax, plenty of people do it.

HTH,

Charley

Comment: Thanks! If plenty of people do it that is a very good sign. I'll take a look at the google group, and for the record that link _is_ to what I refer.

Comment: I was hoping for a ZK/Watir experienced tester to give me a more definite response, and mark this answer correct if no other answers came along, but as it seems a little esoteric I shall do so now.